# How to change elastic cluster name

Tags: elasticsearch

http://xxxxx:9200/_cluster/health?level=indices&pretty=true

gives

```
{
cluster_name: "xx-elastic",
status: "red",
timed_out: false,
number_of_nodes: 3,
number_of_data_nodes: 2,
active_primary_shards: 167,
active_shards: 323,
relocating_shards: 0,
initializing_shards: 0,
.

.
.

.
```

i need to change this cluter_name. I could not do it with xpost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml` configuration file, you can change the following property:

```
cluster.name: xx-elastic
```

to whatever you want and restart your cluster.